# Simulate a mixture distribution in R

Tags: r, simulation, mixture-distribution

Hi just wanna try to simulate a mixture distribution with combination of a **normal distribution** and a **non-central t distribution**,

the random variable Z is defined as:

$$Z = nX+(1-n)Y$$

where

$$n \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\pi) $$

$$ X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_1, \sigma_1) $$

$$ Y \sim t_\nu(\mu_2, 1) $$

i have the codes as below but a bit inefficient, anyone can help to improve?

```
    mix.dist.alt <- function(n,mix.par,mu1,sigma1,mu2,df) {
    #Purpose: Alternative implementation of routine to sample n values
    #  from the mixture distribution
    #Inputs:
    # n - number of samples to return
    # mix.par - pi in the practical notes -- proportion of samples from norm dist
    # mu1 - mean of norm dist
    # sigma1 - sd of norm dist
    # mu2 - mean of t dist
    # df - df for t dist
    #Outputs:
    # vector of n values from the mixture distribution
    #create results vector
    Z<-numeric(n)
    #go through each observation...
    for(i in 1:n){
    #...determine if it comes from the normal or t distribution
    if(rbinom(1,1,mix.par)==1) {
    #normal distribution
    Z[i]<-rnorm(1,mu1,sigma1)
      } else {
    #t distribution
    Z[i]<-mu2+rt(1,df)
     }
        }
    return(Z)
           }
```

Comment: why is the Bernoulli distribution used for the mixing parameter? or what benefit does it provide when mixing two distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much simpler solution is to simply take $k$ values from one distribution and $N-k$ values from the other, where $k$ follows binomial distribution ($N$ Bernoulli trials):

```
mix.dist.alt2 <- function(n, mix.par, mu1, sigma1, mu2, df) {
  k <- rbinom(1, n, mix.par)
  sample(c(rnorm(k, mu1, sigma1), mu2+rt(n-k, df))) #shuffle the values
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your codes, but when i interpret the numbers for the function still an error exists.
      _codes as follow_:
        `n<-10000`
      `mix.par<-3.14`
      `mu1<-0`
       `sigma1<-0`
      `mu2<-1`
      `df<-1`
      **and it returns like:**
      `mix.dist(n,mix.par,mu1,sigma1,mu2,df)`
       `Show Traceback`
 
       `Rerun with Debug`
      `Error in rnorm(k, mu1, sigma1) : invalid arguments In addition: `
       `Warning message:`
      `In rbinom(1, n, mix.par) : NAs produced`

Comment: @ChokinCaby `mix.par` is probability, so has to fit the $[0, 1]$ range.

Comment: yes many thx for the help! I just realized that the range restriction.

Comment: @ChokinCaby In this case `mix.par` is $p$ parameter for [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) or [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) distribution. If you find the answer helpful you can accept it (the "v" button).